# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 3401497278

Tags: android

I was trying to open **cache.properties.lock** file present in .gradle 
[image]

and suddenly Android Studio got crashed with Incompatible magic error popup.
[image]

How to fix this issue? No idea.

Comment: ClassFormatError Sound like different Java Version between compile and runtime

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue a lot while we were sending JAVA classes in an enterprise - this is primarily caused when class (compiled) classes that are sent over mails as attachments and the proxy servers tampers with the content.

This can happen when using a proxy server, and especially when the CLASS files were sent as .TXT extensions to avoid PROXY/FIREWALL blockings to secured enterprise environments.

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow doesn't work like a forum. It's a site where each question has explicit answers to questions. I understand you have < 50 rep, so you should [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).